# Apache commons mail Exception..Recipient address rejected: User unknown in virtual alias table

Tags: java, apache, email, apache-commons-email

I have two emails of my own domain. One is configured in the domain and other is configured in `gmail` (admin.google.com).

### My code

```
    HtmlEmail htmlEmail = new HtmlEmail();
    htmlEmail.setHostName("mydomain.com");
    htmlEmail.setSmtpPort(587);
    htmlEmail.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator(
            "enquiry@mydomain.com", "password"));


        htmlEmail.setFrom("enquiry@mydomain.com", " Enquiry");
        htmlEmail.setSubject("New Enquiry");
        htmlEmail.setHtmlMsg("My message");
        htmlEmail.addTo("info@mydomain.com");

        htmlEmail.send();
```

When I send mail from the domain configured email(enquiry@mydomain.com) to gmail configured email(info@mydomain.com) it shows the following error:

> org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the
>   following server failed : mydomain.com:587
>   at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1421)
>   at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1448)
>   at com.myproject.test.HomeController.sendEmail(HomeController.java:153)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
>     at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:147)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:279)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;   nested exception
>   is:   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 550 5.1.1
>   : Recipient address rejected: User unknown in
>   virtual alias table   at
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.rcptTo(SMTPTransport.java:1949)   at
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1195)
>     at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:254)   at
>   javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)     at
>   org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1411)    ... 39
>   more Caused by: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 550
>   5.1.1 : Recipient address rejected: User unknown in virtual alias table    at
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.rcptTo(SMTPTransport.java:1802)

Answer (score 0):

The root-cause seems to be `Recipient address rejected: User unknown in virtual alias table`, which indicates that the SMTP-server that you are sending to rejects the email because it does not know the email-address that you specified.

So either the email-address is incorrect or the SMTP-server needs to be configured properly to accept this email-address that you specify in the `to` and `sender` fields.